# Linq - How to exclude items from autocomplete array

Tags: linq, methods, autocomplete

I have the following code that gives me a an array in an autocomplete extender:

```
return autocomplete.tblAutoCompletes
                    .Where(p => p.MemberId == memberid && p.LocationId == locationid && p.ACItem.Contains(prefixText))
                    .OrderBy(p => p.ACItem)
                    .Select(p => p.ACItem)
                    .Take(count)
                    .ToArray();
```

However, I may need to programmatically exclude certain items from the array.

How would I do that? So for example, ACItem list = Product1, Product2, Product3.

How would I amend the code so that Product2 is excluded?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
autocomplete.tblAutoCompletes
                .Where(p => p.MemberId == memberid && p.LocationId == locationid && p.ACItem.Contains(prefixText))
                .OrderBy(p => p.ACItem)
                .Select(p => p.ACItem)
                .Take(count)
                .Where(p => p != Product1)
                .Select(p => p)
                .ToArray();
```

Comment: Hello JSmith - so I'd do this outside of the original query? 

Sorry, I'm having a really bad day and being very thick. Thanks for looking at this for me though.

Comment: Seconded. Unless there are additional unstated requirements, it would seem like running the result though another WHERE filter would be the simplest.

Comment: Is there really a need to wrap the first part of the query in parentheses?  At first sight it's hard to see why there's a left parentheses at the beginning.

Comment: Top, top stuff. That's great and gives me a solid foundation to work on. Really appreciate your help.